# List of Strings to char[] in Java

Tags: java, string, char

I have a list of Strings in Java, I would to create an array of Chars instead. Is there a quick and dirty way to do this?

Comment: Do you want each String to be a separate Char array?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a `List<String>` converted to a `List<Char[]>`?

Comment: `List<String>` to `List<Character> `

Comment: Sorry to be vague, @ClickerMonkey has the right idea, I'd like to take a List<String> and output char[] (trying to work with an ill-conceived api call).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean to go from `List<String>` to `char[]` this may be useful

```
public static char[] convertStringListToChars( List<String> stringList ) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for ( String x : stringList ) {
      sb.append( x );
   }
   return sb.toCharArray();
}
```

Or if it's `List<String>` to `char[][]`

```
public static char[][] convertStringListToChars( List<String> stringList ) {
   char[][] chars = new char[ stringList.size() ][];
   for ( int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++ ) {
      chars[i] = stringList.get( i ).toCharArray();
   }
   return chars;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the simplest thing is to append each `String` to a `StringBuilder`, convert this to a `String` and then to a char array using [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).

By creating one (possibly large) string to begin with, you don't have to create a collection of char arrays as an intermediate step. The downside is that intermediate large string (most likely not a problem but something to be aware of)

Answer (score 1):

suppose arrayliststring is the array of strings and arrayListChar is array of char you want

```
ArrayList<char[]> arrayListChar=new ArrayList<char[]>();
for(String str:arrayListStrings)
{
    arrayListChar.add(str.toCharArray());
}
```